# Internet explorer 10 issues with arcgis javascript library

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am using javascript api from arcgis to have map functionality in my application. the script works fine  in all browsers(google chrome, firefox, ie7,8,9). But throws access denied errors in IE 10 and errors look like below. i am not posting any code due to security reasons, and the problem is only with IE 10, so this must be a browser specific issue. Has anyone ran into this issue before?

```
Error: Access is denied.
Error: Access is denied.
   k (http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/:161:153)
   at xhr (http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/:195:207)
   at xhrGet (http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/:195:483)
   at y (http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/:876:354)
   at c (http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/:878:207)
   at x (http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/:884:43)
   at addressToLocations (http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/tasks/locator.js:8:26)
   at _performTask (http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/dijit/Geocoder.js:30:238)
   at _query (http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/dijit/Geocoder.js:26:47)
   at _findQuery (http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/dijit/Geocoder.js:19:440)
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS is happening and IE might be preventing further requests.

Can you try working with a local proxy rather than one hosted on arcgis.com instead?

Comment: Isn't there a proxy.ashx hosted in ArcGIS.com which you used as a pass thru in making ArcGIS calls? If yes, can you host it locally in your machine or server where your app is hosted?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use //js.arcgis.com which should then use the request connection (http/https) scheme.

Also note you have options for configuring requests to use a local proxy and this is documented on the ESRI site:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.   
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.